# Separating sentence into two simpler ones

Tags: sentence, conjunction-reduction

In this sentence:

- *He must be keenly susceptible to people's wants and be able to assess the price at which they would be prepared to satisfy them.*

Can you help me to separate this complex sentence into two sentences?

The relative pronoun *at which* kinda throws me off. Is *which* referring to the price? If so, why the preposition at not with?

Comment: Hello, JD. What have you come up with so far? Try with 'He must be as tall as her and be able to dance' as a simpler exercise.

Comment: The relative pronoun at which kinda throw me off. Is which referring to the price? If so, why the preposition at not with.

Comment: I don't understand ***susceptible to*** here. Perhaps ***perceptive of*** or ***attuned to***?

Comment: Only two? There are at least four clauses here. Where did the question come from? Another incompetent English teacher?

Comment: @John Lawler: Could you please identify the four clauses for me?

Comment: Yes, if you will identify where this question comes from, and why the task is to separate it into two sentences.

Comment: Apparently, that the OP could tell us better than I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word ***moreover*** can sometimes add a little gravitas to a sentence(s). For example,

> He must be keenly susceptible to people's wants. Moreover, he must be able . . ..

I recommend you pare down the sentence, too. Remove a few words. For example,

> He must be keenly susceptible to people's wants. Moreover. he must be able to determine a price that will satisfy them.

Comment: Thanks . This helps a lot^^

Comment: @JDCruz. You're welcome, JD!

Comment: And uhm.. more questions if you don't mind. In the relative clause, "at which they would be prepared to satisfy them....... is which referring to the price? Is the  antecedent of "they" the people's wants?